# Как созданный массив использовать в других кнопках(windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Я создал в одной кнопке двумерный массив, как в другой кнопке сделать ,чтобы он проверял что нибудь в этом массиве и в textBox выводил ответ

```
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox6.Visible = true; textBox7.Visible = true; button7.Visible = true;
            stolb = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); strok = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            nach_chislo = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); end_chislo=int.Parse(textBox4.Text);


            int[,] mass = new int[stolb, strok];
            int v_stolb = mass.GetLength(0); int v_stroku = mass.GetLength(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < stolb; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < strok; j++)
                {
                    mass[i, j] = random.Next(nach_chislo, end_chislo);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < v_stolb; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < v_stroku; j++)
                {
                    iznach += mass[i, j] + " ";
                }
                iznach += Environment.NewLine;
                textBox5.Text = iznach.ToString();
            }


            foreach (var x in mass)
            {
                if (p1 <= x && x <= p2)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox8.Text = count.ToString();
        }
```

[image: как сделать чтобы когда я нажимал результат он вывел count по условию]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас массив объявлен как локальная переменная

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    int[,] mass = new int[stolb, strok];

    // ...     
}
```

Объявите его как поле, и сможете использовать в других методах

```
private int[,] mass;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    mass = new int[stolb, strok];

    // ...     
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но у меня все равно почему то выводит count как 0 в textBox

Comment: @miracle речь шла про массив, а не про count, так?

Comment: да, я вроде нашел как чтобы оно работало. Большое спасибо